# Get attribute values

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Basically I have the xml file format likes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<retentions>
   <client id="1544">
      <facility id="5436">
         <retention period="23" />
      </facility>
   </client>
   <client id="7353">
      <facility id="3450">
        <retention period="3" />
     </facility>
   </client>
</retentions>
```

I want to get all values of all attributes such as "1554", "5436", "23" etc.

Please use XDocument instead of XMLDocument.
My code is wrong:

```
XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load("my.xml");
   IEnumerable<XElement> results = (from el in XDoc.Root.Elements("retentions")
                                         select el);
```

**UPDATE:**(Using dictionary)

```
var g = from element in XDoc.Descendants("client")
                from ID in element.Attributes("id")
                from Facility in element.Attributes("facility")
                from Period in element.Attributes("period")
                select new { Key = ID.Value, Value = Period.Value };
```

Comment: In my opinion this should help you sove the linq: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333751/linq-to-xml-select-all-attributes-and-their-values-for-a-given-node

Comment: is there a Typo in your code..? should this `XDoc.Root.Element("retentions")` be `XDoc.Root.Elements("retentions")`

Comment: You are right, I modified it. But I still need guildiance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One line to get all attributes from xml document:

```
var attributes = ((IEnumerable)xdoc.XPathEvaluate("//@*"))
                      .Cast<XAttribute>().Select(a => (string)a);
```

UPDATE (dictionary of all nodes attributes)

```
var attributes = xdoc.Descendants()
                    .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.LocalName,
                                  g => g.SelectMany(x => x.Attributes())
                                        .Select(a => (string)a)
                                        .ToList());

List<string> attributesOfClient = attributes["client"];
```

Comment: System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'XPathEvaluate' and no extension method 'XPathEvaluate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Love you should add namespace `using System.Xml.XPath;` where this extension is declared

Comment: Then another error Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: IEnumerable is un System.Collections namespace (it is not the generic version)

Comment: @Love add namespace `using System.Collections;` BTW set cursor on class name which is not found and press Ctrl+Shift+F10 - Visual Studio will suggest you to add missing namespace reference

Answer (score 2):

To get the attributes of an element:

```
XElement xElement;
IEnumerable attributes = xElement.Attributes();
```

to get all the elements of a document:

```
XDocument xDocument;
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xDocument.Descendants();
```

Then, using LINQ:
All the values are:

```
from element in xDocument.Descendants()
from attribute in element.Attributes()
select attribute.Value;
```

Is this what you want?

#### UPDATE

```
var dictionary = xDocument.Descendants("client").ToDictionary(element => element, element =>
    (from descendant in element.Descendants()  // Gets descendant elements of element
    from attribute in descendant.Attributes()  // Gets all the attributes of the descendant
    select attribute.Value).ToList());
```

#### UPDATE 2

```
var g = XDoc.Descendants("client")
        .ToDictionary(element => element.Attribute("id").Value,
                      element => new 
                                 {                                 
                                     element.Descendants("facility").First().Attribute("id").Value, 
                                     element.Descendants("retention").First().Attribute("period").Value 
                                  });
```

Comment: It seems to be working, if I want to create a dictionary to store all attributes for each node, how to do it?

Comment: @Love can you describe your goal more clear? Give an example of dictionary for your sample xml?

Comment: By the sample data. Let's say: {1544,5436_23};{7353,3450_3}.

Comment: What the underscore "_" means?  And what is the key of each item in the dictionary?

Comment: The first one client id's value is the key. I combine the other two values(facility id and period id) with underscore '_' as the value in the dictionary.

Comment: So you want to get all the dictionary with the client id as Key and the list of attributes in the client as Value?

Comment: Then what is the dictionary name?

Comment: @Love , What do you mean by the dictionary name? If it is the name of the variable, I've edited the post.

Comment: I tried your code, it displays all xml node like a tree rather than attributes. Can you look at my updated code and modify it?