# Grab multiple instances of a node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a block of an XML file here. I want to grab all the instances of the ToyId and put it in an array. As well as only grab the node with the "Hastoys = "YES"" attribute.

```xml
<Bookstore Hastoys="YES"> 
  <Authors>7</Authors>
  <Location>Austin TX</Location>
  <Employees>15</Employees>
  <ToyList>
    <ToyId>124</ToyId>
    <ToyId>1251</ToyId>
  </ToyList>
  <ToyList>
    <ToyId>255-2</ToyId>
    <ToyId>6623</ToyID>
  </ToyList>
</Bookstore>
```

```cs
var list =  from r in doc.Descendants("Bookstore")
            .Where(node => (string)node.Attribute("HasToys") == "YES")
            select new
            {
                ToyId = r.Element("ToyList")?.Element("ToyId")?.Value,
            };
```

I tried using the query above but its only returning me the first instance of toy id then goes to the next block. So the output would be: 124, and skip the other toyids.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333751/linq-to-xml-select-all-attributes-and-their-values-for-a-given-node

Answer (score 2):

Few issues/concerns from your XML:

1. Invalid closing tag for

```
<ToyId>6623</ToyID>
```

2. The attribute in `Bookstore` element is "Hastoys"

```
<Bookstore Hastoys="YES">
```

But your code is referring "HasToys"

```
(string)node.Attribute("HasToys") == "YES"
```

**Approach 1**

Assume that you fixed the mentioned issues/concerns, working with `.Descendants("ToyList").Elements("ToyId")` to get each `ToyId` element under the `ToyList` elements.

```cs
string xml = @"<Bookstore HasToys=""YES""> 
    <Authors>7</Authors>
    <Location>Austin TX</Location>
    <Employees>15</Employees>
    <ToyList>
        <ToyId>124</ToyId>
        <ToyId>1251</ToyId>
    </ToyList>
    <ToyList>
        <ToyId>255-2</ToyId>
        <ToyId>6623</ToyId>
    </ToyList>
</Bookstore>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var list = (from r in doc.Descendants("Bookstore")
              .Where(node => (string)node.Attribute("HasToys") == "YES")
                .Descendants("ToyList")
                .Elements("ToyId")
              select new
              {
                    ToyId = r.Value,
              });
```

---

**Approach 2**

You may work with XPath as well

```cs
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
var list = root.SelectNodes("//Bookstore[@HasToys='YES']/ToyList/ToyId").Cast<XmlNode>()    
    .Select(x => new
              {
                    ToyId = x.InnerText
              })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LloB9s)

Comment: [Demo Approach 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FIqRxW)

Comment: It's still only grabbing the first instance of ToyId. It would print out "124" then "255-2" and skip the second instance.

Comment: Have you click in the demo link I shared and see the result?